# Paginated Menu List

Tags: php, silverstripe

How do a I create a paginated menu list of children (i.e. `Menu(2)`).  I tried

```
$list = Menu::get();
```

but class Menu does not exist.  Is it best to iterate Menu(2) and assign it to a DataArray? I also tried

```
$list = Page::get();
```

but it doesn't even show any pages?

Comment: where are the silverstripe gurus, need help on this.

Comment: @3dgoo thanks a lot, I appreciate your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SilverStripe 3.1 we can call [`$this->getMenu(2)`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-ContentController.html#_getMenu) in our controller to get the navigation menu of the given level (level 2 in this case).

We can then use [`PaginatedList`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-PaginatedList.html) to turn that menu into a paginated list. There are some great resources on how to create a paginated list such as:

1. [How to Create a Paginated List](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/templates/how_tos/pagination/)
2. [Lesson - Lists and Pagination](http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/lists-and-pagination)

We can use these to create a PaginatedMenu function that will return a paginated list of our menu items:

```php
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

    public function PaginatedMenu($level = 1) {
        $paginatedMenu = PaginatedList::create(
            $this->getMenu($level), 
            $this->request
        );
        $paginatedMenu->setPageLength(5);
        $paginatedMenu->setPaginationGetVar('menu-start');

        return $paginatedMenu;
    }
}
```

[`setPageLength`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-PaginatedList.html#_setPageLength) allows us to set the number of items to display per page.

Here is an example of how to use this in our template:

```html
<% if $PaginatedMenu(2) %>
    <ul class="paginatedMenu">
        <% loop $PaginatedMenu(2) %>
        <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a></li>
        <% end_loop %>
    </ul>

    <% if $PaginatedMenu(2).MoreThanOnePage %>
        <div class="pagination">
            <% if $PaginatedMenu(2).NotFirstPage %>
            <a href="$PaginatedMenu(2).PrevLink" class="prev" aria-label="View the previous page">&larr;</a>
            <% end_if %>
            <span>
                <% loop $PaginatedMenu(2).PaginationSummary %>
                    <% if $CurrentBool %>
                    $PageNum
                    <% else_if $PageNum %>
                    <a href="$Link" class="pageLink" aria-label="View page number $PageNum">$PageNum</a>
                    <% end_if %>
                <% end_loop %>
            </span>
            <% if $PaginatedMenu(2).NotLastPage %>
            <a href="$PaginatedMenu(2).NextLink" class="next" aria-label="View the next page">&rarr;</a>
            <% end_if %>
        </div>

        <p>Page $PaginatedMenu(2).CurrentPage of $PaginatedMenu(2).TotalPages</p>
    <% end_if %>
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: You're the best or at least one of the best Silverstripe gurus. Thank you very much!